# How to dispatch an action with delay (debounce)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, promise, debouncing

I have a scenario where I need to dispatch an action two seconds after a input is completed. (Let's say a user type 1000 without an interval of 2 seconds, so I need to dispatch action only after 1000 is typed and after 2 seconds from it).

Previously I used [debounce-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debounce-promise) to do such a thing, where I needed to get dropdown list from API, but for that I directly used the library with AJAX call in component. It worked correctly.

Now I need to dispatch an action like this.

```
  // should be dispatched only for the last request
  const getRateReq = dispatch(getRates());

  const getRate = debounce(getRateReq, 2000, {
    leading: false,
  });

  const onChange = (e) => {
     setValue(e.target.value);
     getRate(e.target.value);
  }
```

Now also the action dispatches only after two seconds of completing the typing. But then it makes all the requests for 1, 10, 100, 1000 (even though 1000 is inputted without two seconds interval). How can I get this fixed and dispatch an action only for the last input in 2 seconds ?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

EDIT : Added the basic onChange function

Answer (score 5):

you can do something like this.

```
let timeOut = null;
SearchFilter: (name, value) => {
    clearTimeout(timeOut);
    dispatch(SearchFilter(name, value));
    timeOut = setTimeout(() => {
            dispatch(callfunction());
        }, 2000);
    }
```

it will dispatch the action waiting 2 second for the input.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this. Btw, what I need is to dispatch an action on last input within 2 seconds interval. So, if user type just 1 and wait for 2 seconds then the action should be dispatched. And if user type 100 without a 2 seconds delay in between the action should be dipsatched for 100 only (not 1 or 10). This is what I want.

Comment: you can add delay in onchange function then

Comment: But then the value also changes with delay right ? But what I need is change the value instantly (on onChange function), but dispatch action only for the last input within 2 seconds interval.

Comment: what is the criteria of last input? and how would you know that this is the last input?

Comment: if the input doesn't change within two seconds the action should be dispatched.

e.g : 

1) type `1` and wait 2 seconds action should be dispatched.
2) type `1` then `0` (10) without 2 seconds without any delay in between and wait 2 seconds. Then the action should be dispatched for value of `10`

so, the action should be dispatched considering the value of last input in 2 seconds interval.

Comment: I have edited my answer, now It will change input and wait for 2 seconds if the input is not changed till 2 second it will dispatch the action, if the input is changed it will restart the timer of 2 second by clearTimeout() function

Comment: Ok Thanks I'll try this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201712/discussion-between-thidasa-pankaja-and-saqib-naseeb).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the debounce method of loadash and do something like:

```
onChange = debounce(anyInput => {
    }, 2000);
```

so you have to make your API call within the onchange method when you finished typing and 2 seconds after that.
Not sure this is what you are asking?

Comment: I'll try this. Btw, what I need is to dispatch an action on last input within 2 seconds interval. So, if user type just 1 and wait for 2 seconds then the action should be dispatched. And if user type 100 without a 2 seconds delay in between the action should be dipsatched for 100 only (not 1 or 10). This is what I want.
Btw, Thanks

Comment: That is exactly how this method works. It waits for change in input for number of seconds specified and then only gets applied if 2 seconds are gone. If you type 100 immediately without having a delay, it will only run for 100 and not for 1 and 10.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <input onChange={_.debounce((e)=> dispatch(search(e.target.value)), 300)} />
```

Can do something like this and remember to import the lodash and dispatch